# CLN not recognized by compiler

Tags: c++, libraries

I have installed CLN from cygwin and it has an examples folder. I copied an example and tried to compile it and it wont let me

```
#include <cln/real.h>
#include <cln/integer.h>
#include <cln/io.h>
#include <cln/integer_io.h>
#include <cln/numtheory.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cln;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cl_R x = (cl_R) n;
    cl_I p = nextprobprime(x);
    cout << p << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It gives an error

```
fatal error: cln/real.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <cln/real.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My plan was to install ginac so I had to install cln first. Do I need to add a path variable or something to allow it to compile? If so how do I do that

Also is it possible to write

```
#include <cln>
```

or something like this so that all headers are included instead of doing it one by one. This is my first external library. I plan to use more

Comment: In cygwin locate where the headers for cln are.

Comment: For your second question about `#include <cln>` something like this is usually a bad practice that increases build times

Comment: They are in a .tar.bz2 format inside the release folder. I got the example file from extracting the cln-1.3.3-1.tar.bz2  to  cln-1.3.3-1 which had an examples folder.

Comment: You probably need to build it from source.

Comment: How do I do that. Is there any tutorial that can walk me through this step by step. Please send link. I am completely stuck